# PHP DOMDocument parse HTML

Tags: php, xpath, html-parsing, domdocument

I have the following HTML markup

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="text"></div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="text"></div>
<div style="display: block;" class="ui-draggable">
    <img class='avatar' src=""/>
    <p style="">
    <img class='pic' src=""/><br>
    <span class='fulltext' style="display:none"></span>
    </p>-<span class='create'></span>
    <a class='permalink' href=""></a>
    </div>
 <div contenteditable="true" class="text"></div>
 <div style="display: block;" class="ui-draggable">
    <img class='avatar' src=""/>
    <p style="">
    <img class='pic' src=""/><br>
    <span class='fulltext' style="display:none"></span>
    </p><span class='create'></span><a class='permalink' href=""></a>
    </div>
```

The parent div's can be more.In order to parse the information and to insert it in the DB I'm using the following code -

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div');
$i=0;
$q=1;
foreach($div as $book) {
    $attr = $book->getAttribute('class');
    //if div contenteditable
    if($attr == 'text') {
        echo '</br>'.$book->nodeValue."</br>";  
    }
    
    else {
        $new = new DOMDocument();
        $newxpath = new DOMXPath($new);
        $avatar = $xpath->query("(//img[@class='avatar']/@src)[$q]");
        
        $picture = $xpath->query("(//p/img[@class='pic']/@src)[$q]");
        $fulltext = $xpath->query("(//p/span[@class='fulltext'])[$q]");
        $permalink = $xpath->query("(//a[@class='permalink'])[$q]");
        echo $permalink->item(0)->nodeValue; //date
        echo $permalink->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
        echo $fulltext->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo $avatar->item(0)->value;
        echo $picture->item(0)->value;
        $q++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But I think that there's a better way for parsing the HTML. Is there? Thank you in advance

Comment: `$avatar = $avatar;` is useless

Comment: yeah, I've missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [`DOMXPath::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) supports a second param called `contextparam`. Also you won't need a second DOMDocument and DOMXPath inside the loop. Use:

```
$avatar = $xpath->query("img[@class='avatar']/@src", $book);
```

to get `<img src="">` attribute nodes relative to the div nodes. If you follow my advices your example should be fine.

---

Here comes a version of your code that follows the above said:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query('//div');

foreach($divs as $book) {
    $attr = $book->getAttribute('class');
    if($attr == 'text') {
        echo '</br>'.$book->nodeValue."</br>";  
    } else {
        $avatar = $xpath->query("img[@class='avatar']/@src", $book);
        $picture = $xpath->query("p/img[@class='pic']/@src", $book);
        $fulltext = $xpath->query("p/span[@class='fulltext']", $book);
        $permalink = $xpath->query("a[@class='permalink']", $book);
        echo $permalink->item(0)->nodeValue; //date
        echo $permalink->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
        echo $fulltext->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo $avatar->item(0)->value;
        echo $picture->item(0)->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" - `echo $picture->..`, `echo $fulltext->..`

Comment: Can you post the full HTML to pastebin?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. One last question - what's the difference between `nodeValue`, `value` and `textValue` ?

Comment: In the example above you are sometimes selecting DOMElement nodes -> nodeValue, DOMAttribute nodes -> value.. I'm unsure about textValue. Expecting it the value of a DOMTextNode or the textual, flattened representation of a DOMElementNode's childs

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, you do it the right way : html has to be parsed with a DOM object.
Then some optimisation can be brough :

```
$div = $xpath->query('//div');
```

is quite greedy, a getElementsByTagName should be more appropriate :

```
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Comment: I have doubts about the use of `$q`

Comment: @artragis Note that both statements will return the same value. In any case.

Comment: getElementsByTagName is bufferized so it is less greedy in memory. Let me find the message on @internals list and show it to you as an evidence.